# EF Code First, create new object in collection with a proxy

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

How can I create+persist+have-a-proxy-to a new instance of a code-first poco using only navigation property collections? In the bellow code, I show how you might want to do this, if using member functions to create POCOs that then create POCOs. You don't have a DbContext, but if you create an object and persist it using DbSet.Add, the returned object isn't a proxy, so you can't in turn use its DbSet.Add to add a different sub-object.

In this code, if you call MailingList.AddIncomingMessage("my message"), you get an exception at the "OOPS" comment, because the created msg isn't a proxy and thus its Message.doodads property is null.

```
class Doodad {
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string doodad { get; set; };
}

class Message {
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public virtual MailingList mailingList { get; set; } 
  public virtual ICollection<Doodad> doodads { get; set; }
  public string text { get; set; }

  public void GetDoodadCreateIfNeeded(string doodad) {
    try {
      // won't be found since we just created this Message
      return this.doodads.First(d => d.doodad == doodad);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Doodad newDoodad = new Doodad() { doodad=doodad };

      // OOPS! this.doodads == null, because its not a proxy object
      this.doodads.Add(newDoodad);
      return newDoodad;
    }
  }
}

class MailingList {
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Message> messages { get; set; }

  public void AddIncomingMessage(string message) {
    var msg = new Message() { text=message };

    // we have no Context, because we're in a POCO's member function
    this.messages.Add(msg);

    var doodad = msg.GetDoodadCreateIfNeeded("bongo drums");
  }
}
```

EDIT: sorry guys, I forgot to put the property accessors and ID in for this simplified case, but I am using them in the actual code.

Comment: to anyone else running into this, check out Alex's comment on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974448/entityframework-4-1-dbcontext-changetracking-kills-performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with proxies. It is the same as any other code - if you want to use object / collection you must first initialize it! Your fist command:

```
return this.doodads.First(d => d.doodad == doodad);
```

doesn't throw exception because it didn't find `doodad` but because the `doodads` is null.

What do you need to do? You need to initialize collections before you first use them. You can do it:

- Directly in their definition
- In entity's constructor
- In property getter (lazy initialization) once they are first needed - that would require to change your fields to properties which is btw. correct way to write classes in .NET
- In your custom methods you can check if they are null and initialize them

Comment: I've been concerned about adding constructors, because I don't want to overwrite data from the DB... e.g. if I have: public Message() { this.doodads = new IList<Doodad>(); }, will that accidentally overwrite data loaded from the DB when there are already associations for doodads, or will it only be called before data is loaded (or only called when I explicitly do a new)?

Comment: When I explicitly initialize doodads with the above constructor, when I later try to context.SaveChanges() I get: InvalidOperationException "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.". I think maybe I do need a proxy?

Comment: Ladislav, could you give an example of initialing a collection? I'm currently creating a new List<Doodad>, and getting an error when I do so. Should I use a different type than List?

Comment: InvalidOperationException "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."

Comment: Put the relevant code into your question. Simple initialization should not produce this error.

Comment: Constructors are not executed when objects are deserialized with DataContractSerializer.  This *interesting* design choice makes the constructor a bad place to initialize the class if there is any chance the object might be serialized now or in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Complementary to the navigation property, you need to have a property that is the Id of the foreign key.

So your MailingList will need to have this property:

```
  [Key] // this attribute is important
  public int Id { get; set; }
```

and you'll have to change the Message classe to have these properties:

```
public virtual int mailingListId { get; set; 
public virtual MailingList mailingList { get; set; }
```

The `{ get; set; }` property is important, so that it is a property, not just a public attribute.

Comment: good catch Doug, I forgot to include these when I made the simplified example to try and more clearly explain my problem.