# Entity Framework + LINQ + "Contains" == Super Slow?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Trying to refactor some code that has gotten really slow recently and I came across a code block that is taking 5+ seconds to execute.

The code consists of 2 statements:

```
IEnumerable<int> StudentIds = _entities.Filters
                    .Where(x => x.TeacherId == Profile.TeacherId.Value && x.StudentId != null)
                    .Select(x => x.StudentId)
                    .Distinct<int>();
```

and

```
_entities.StudentClassrooms
                    .Include("ClassroomTerm.Classroom.School.District")
                    .Include("ClassroomTerm.Teacher.Profile")
                    .Include("Student")
                    .Where(x => StudentIds.Contains(x.StudentId)
                    && x.ClassroomTerm.IsActive
                    && x.ClassroomTerm.Classroom.IsActive
                    && x.ClassroomTerm.Classroom.School.IsActive
                    && x.ClassroomTerm.Classroom.School.District.IsActive).AsQueryable<StudentClassroom>();
```

So it's a bit messy but first I get a Distinct list of Id's from one Table (Filters), then I query another Table using it.

These are relatively small tables, but it's still 5+ seconds of query time.

I put this in LINQPad and it showed that it was doing the bottom query first then running 1000 "distinct" queries afterwards.

On a whim I changed the "StudentIds" code by just adding .ToArray() at the end.  This improved the speed 1000x ... it now takes like 100ms to complete the same query.

What's the deal?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `What am I doing wrong?`  Erm... Not making StudentID's an array? :)

Comment: In other news, isn't Linqpad a cool tool?

Comment: This is one of those cases where 'var' would have magically made the code faster by identifying that StudentIds could be IQueryable.

Comment: @insta Hmm, I just tested that and got very different results... in my case... IEnumerable=5.5 seconds, var=24 seconds, IEnumerable+ToArray=300ms

Comment: I might be assuming indexes exist that don't :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does the Contains() operator degrade Entity Framework's performance so dramatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897630/why-does-the-contains-operator-degrade-entity-frameworks-performance-so-drama)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is one of the pitfalls of deferred execution in Linq: In your first approach `StudentIds` is really an `IQueryable`, not an in-memory collection. That means using it in the second query will run the query again on the database - each and every time.

Forcing execution of the first query by using `ToArray()` makes `StudentIds` an in-memory collection and the `Contains` part in your second query will run over this collection that contains a fixed sequence of items - This gets mapped to something equivalent to a SQL `where StudentId in (1,2,3,4)` query.

This query will of course, be much much faster since you determined this sequence once up-front, and not every time the `Where` clause is executed. Your second query without using `ToArray()` (I would think) would be mapped to a SQL query with an `where exists (...)` sub-query that gets evaluated for each row.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think far enough ahead as to why it would ever want to not make an in-memory collection first.  I just assumed and you know what happens when you assume :-P

Comment: I don't understand it :( I'd agree about the deferred execution argument *if* the second query would be LINQ to Objects. But apparently it's LINQ to Entities. The second query is translated into SQL (only once) and then the SQL is executed. Also for the expression the *declared* type of `StudentIds` is important, not the runtime type. It's a difference if you use `IEnumerable<int>` or if you use `var` (= `IQueryable<int>`). In the first case the first query is executed once and the second query tranlates to `IN`, the second case is `exist(subquery)`. I don't know where 1000 queries come from.

Comment: @Slauma: Looking at it with fresh eyes today I think you are right - there should only be two cases - either the `where in..` query or the `where exists (subquery)`. The later might be less efficient (i.e. missing some indexes) so it explains why using `IQueryable` will perform worse than `IEnumerable` in this case. It does not however explain the difference seen when using `ToArray()`. OP's timing results also seem to indicate that each of the 3 versions (IEnumerable, IQueryable, IEnumerable+ToArray) has vastly different performance characteristics. Maybe an expert can chip in.

Answer (score 4):

`ToArray()` Materializes the initial query to the server memory.

My guess would be the query provider is not able to parse the expression `StudentIds.Contains(x.StudentId)`. Hence it probably thinks that the `studentIds` is an array already loaded to memory. So it's probably querying the database over and over again during the parsing phase. The only way to know for sure is to setup the profiler.

If you need to do this on the db server, use a join, instead of "contains". If you need to use contains to do what looks like a join problem, you are likely to be missing a surrogate primary key or a foreign key somewhere.

You could also declare `studentIds` as IQueryable instead of IEnumerable. This might give the query provider the hint it needs to interpret the `studentIds` as expression aka. data not already loaded to memory. I somehow doubt this but worth a try.

If all else fails, use `ToArray()`. This will load the initial `studentIds` to memory.

Comment: +1 for the recommendation to restructure this into a join.  The more student ids that they have, the less scalable a contains/in will be.