# Compare an huge list with a database table records in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a huge list of strings and I want to compare a database table's records with it. What is the best solution?

You can suppose specified table's name is `ATable` and its structure is like:

```
public class ATable
{
    [Key]
    public long Id{get;set;}
    [Key]
    public long Name{get;set;}
}
```

I wrote the following code

```
using(var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    context.Log = (log) => {Console.WriteLine(log)};
    var result = context.ATables.Where(item => hugeList.Contains(item.Name)).ToList();
}
```

I checked generated logs and I saw that above code translated to SQL `IN(...)` statement and because of hugeness of list application crash.

I'm sure there is a good way to solve this problem, then you professionals can show me right one.

Thanks

Comment: You can use `context.ATables.ToList()` to save it in memory as object. And then check the condition between two .net objects.

Comment: You are right, but if my table's record be huge too then what?

Comment: In my opinion, you can create a new table. And then insert this list items to this table. And then join these two tables with the help of Linq-To-Entity. And after getting the result, you can truncate the first table.

Comment: It is not bad idea but I like to gather more recommendations. thanks

Comment: You might consider breaking the `hugeList` into smaller chunks.. say, 20 values at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [EF 6 Alpha 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/12/10/ef6-alpha-2-available-on-nuget.aspx), EF  includes an improvement that accelerates the translation of Enumerable.Contains.

If you are using an earlier version of EF or the size of your list is too big, as propose @Dan-o you can break the huge list in smaller chunks. To do this you can use the solution that @divega wrote in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897630/why-does-the-contains-operator-degrade-entity-frameworks-performance-so-drama/7936350#7936350). Below I adapt that solution to your problem context:

```
public partial class MyDbContext
{
    public IEnumerable<ATable> GetElements(IEnumerable<long> hugeList, int chunkSize = 100)
    {
        foreach (var chunk in hugeList.Chunk(chunkSize))
        {
            var q = ATables.Where(a => chunk.Contains(a.Name));
            foreach (var item in q)
            {
                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Extension methods for slicing enumerable sequences:

```
public static class EnumerableSlicing
{

    private class Status
    {
        public bool EndOfSequence;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<T> TakeOnEnumerator<T>(IEnumerator<T> enumerator, int count,
        Status status)
    {
        while (--count > 0 && (enumerator.MoveNext() || !(status.EndOfSequence = true)))
        {
            yield return enumerator.Current;
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Chunk<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, int chunkSize)
    {
        if (chunkSize < 1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Chunks should not be smaller than 1 element");
        }
        var status = new Status { EndOfSequence = false };
        using (var enumerator = items.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (!status.EndOfSequence)
            {
                yield return TakeOnEnumerator(enumerator, chunkSize, status);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
var result= context.GetElements(hugelist).ToList();
```