# Define WHERE "value" IN(1,2,3) in ASP.NET Entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework

I have this part of code:

```
ViewBag.myFeedbacks = db.feedbacks.Where(f => f.project_id ?)
```

what should I replace char ? , when I want define something like this :

project_id IN (1,2,3)

so, select all feedback, which have project_id from list of values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var projectIds = new[]{1, 2, 3};

ViewBag.myFeedbacks = db.feedbacks.Where(f => projectIds.Any(p => p == f.project_id))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ViewBag.myFeedbacks = db.feedbacks.Where(f => new[]{1,2,3}.Contains(f.project_id));
```

`IQueryable.Contains` is specialized to emit `... in ...` SQL code.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
db.feedbacks.Where(f => yourArray.Contains(f.project_id))
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897630/why-does-the-contains-operator-degrade-entity-frameworks-performance-so-drama

Comment: please specify your question or comment to my answer. if it's connected to bad performance of `Contains` expression I must assure you that since EF6 this was successfully fixed and works relatively fast now.

Comment: just in case he wasn't using EF6+ which is quite possible.